# How to change imageview content between color and image programmatically?

Tags: android, image, colors, imageview

I'm trying to create a program where when i click on an image view i switch the content of it between a color and an image. I tried this 2 controls: setBackgroundCOlor and setColorFilter but if the imageview is already showing an image the first one will set the color of a layer behind the image, and the second one will color all the image with that color, so the next times i will not see the image anymore.

I used this code lines:

these for the background

```
ImageView imagecolor= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
imagecolor.setBackgroundColorsetColorFilter(Color.BLACK, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

and these for the colorfilter

```
ImageView imagecolor= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
imagecolor.setColorFiltersetColorFilter(Color.BLACK, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

to set the imageview i used this code

```
ImageView imagecolor= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
imagecolor.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
```

I was wondering if there is a control that allows me to work with images and colors on the same layer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have your bitmap replaced with solid color, just do ordinary [setImageResource()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource(int)), i.e.

```
iv.setImageResource(Color.BLACK);
```